# wp_insert_post() with HTML tags with PHP

Tags: php, html, wordpress

This question seem to be unanswered. I find myself stuck on it. Here it goes

I've a problem with WP API to insert a post with HTML Tags.

I'm using the method: **wp_insert_post()** and the content is like this:

`$content = "<p> <img src="img-link"> </p> <p> Hi, this is an example of the content.</p> <a class="dl" href="link-address"> Link Name</a>";`

The result I want when I publish the post is:

**A formatted post applying the html where necessary.**

But the result I have when I publish the post is:

`<p> <img src="img-link"> </p> <p> Hi, this is an example of the content.</p> <a class="dl" href="link-address"> Link Name</a>`

**When I go to the WP Editor to edit the same POST Directly, The Visual Editor looks well formatted as expected**

And The then I navigate to Text Editor as see this well formatted too:

`<p> <img src="img-link"> </p> <p> Hi, this is an example of the content.</p> <a class="dl" href="link-address"> Link Name</a>`

It's quite obvious that this is what I actually want. But When I do this post from my php file  as stated earlier, I get this published:

`<p> <img src="img-link"> </p> <p> Hi, this is an example of the content.</p> <a class="dl" href="link-address"> Link Name</a>`

**MY CODE**

```
$content="<p> <img src="img-link"> </p> <p> Hi, this is an example of the content.</p> <a class="dl" href="link-address"> Link Name</a>";

$my_post = array( 
'post_title' => $title, 
'post_status' => 'publish', 
'post_content' => $content,
'post_author' => 1, 
'post_category' => array(8,39)); 

$post_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post );
```

**I HAVE TRIED**
`html_entity_decode($content);`

And

```
remove_filter('content_save_pre', 'wp_filter_post_kses');

remove_filter('content_filtered_save_pre', 'wp_filter_post_kses');
```

Before Inserting to DB and

```
add_filter('content_save_pre', 'wp_filter_post_kses');

add_filter('content_filtered_save_pre', 'wp_filter_post_kses');
```

After The insert

My script only have the `wp-load.php` loaded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently This was a solution that finally worked.

```
$title = "My news";
$content='<p> <img src="img-link"> </p> <p> Hi, this is an example of the content.</p> <a class="dl" href="link-address"> Link Name</a>';

$postData = array(
    'post_title' => $title,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_content' => $content,
    'post_author' => 1,
    'post_type'         =>   'post',
    'post_category' => array()
);

//Here is the Magic:
kses_remove_filters(); //This Turns off kses
$id = wp_insert_post($postData);
kses_init_filters(); //This Turns on kses again
```

The Original Question was asked by me and a solution was provided on [stackexchange HERE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/368433/wp-insert-post-with-html-tags-using-php/368450#368450)