# wp_insert_post() including HTML in post_content is not working

Tags: php, wordpress

In Wordpress, am trying to generate a page programmatically. And for the page's content, I want to use this HTML (am just putting a little bit of it here):

```
<div class="thrv_wrapper thrv-page-section" data-inherit-lp-settings="1" style="" data-css="tve-u-1839e69caf1">
...
</strong></span></span></a></div></div></div></div></div></div>
```

However the generated page is not displaying this content. My PHP code is this (placed inside my plugin's main PHP file):

```
$content = str_replace('\r\n','',$content);
$content = html_entity_decode($content);
$content = str_replace('<','&lt;',$content);
$content = str_replace('>','&gt;',$content);
// create page
$postData = array(
    'comment_status' => 'close',
    'ping_status'    => 'close',
    'post_author'    => 1,
    'post_title'     => ucwords('title_of_the_page'),
    'post_name'      => strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', trim('title_of_the_page'))),
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'post_content'   => $content,
    'post_type'      => 'page'
);
kses_remove_filters();
wp_insert_post($postData);
kses_init_filters();
```

The code is working fine when I replace `$content` with a normal string like this: `'post_content' => 'test'`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [wp\_insert\_post() with HTML tags with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62241775/wp-insert-post-with-html-tags-with-php)

Comment: @PlamenNikolov No it does not, I literally tried this solution before posting the question, as you can see, I have implemented that exact code and its not working.

Comment: Your code escapes the HTML entities(using `&lt;` and `&gt;`), the referenced answer passes the HTML tags unmodified. Why are you replacing those?

Comment: Because I already tried that and that's not working either. I tried without `str_replace` or `html_entity_decode` and doing it just as the referenced answer suggests, still won't work.

Comment: Do you have the Jetpack plugin enabled?

Comment: No, I already checked.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that some installed plugins may be trying to `sanitize` the content, in such cases remove all the filters is the only option, try the following:

```php
// Try each one of the following and comment what is redundant, 
// Removing all filters would compromise the built-in security layers
remove_all_filters( 'content_save_pre' );
remove_all_filters( 'pre_content');
remove_all_filters( 'content_pre' );

wp_insert_post( $postData );
```

**Important:** Use with caution! Removing all the filters is a really bad idea. There are filters that prevent for example PHP code being injected into the database... so you should find the right filter to remove and use `remove_filter()` only to it. In all cases you should ensure that the content you are programatically inserting is not malicious.